# Development of vitreous humor

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, embryology, development, human-eye

I have tried reading about development of vitreous humor but it is all very confusing. When does it first developed ? Does it renew itself ? Please provide reliable sources..

Answer (score 2):

Look at this scheme -

[image]

As I stated before, vitreous is 99% water and is **not an organ itself**, thus the "replacement of vitreous" is actually = 99% water re-production and the only organ inside the eye which can perform this - ciliary body.

Consequently, if the vitreous was removed and replaced by gas or saline it will be replaced by aqueous which produced by ciliary body - this process takes 8 weeks to completely replace foreign substance as a gas by aqueous.